# Reduce GDI objects created on resize C#

Tags: c#, resize, gdi

I am very concerned about GDI objects and the limit imposed by this to a Windows application (10000 GDI objects per app), as I previously hit the limit with faulty code I have written. Now, I have corrected most of the code, but one thing still catches my attention: the GDI objects count when I resize the form. Every time I resize it, it creates around 20-25 new GDI objects which I think it is pretty bad. I commented my resize code and run the program to test how resizing works again and unfortunately, it still leaked some 19-23/24 GDI objects per resize.

Now what I am asking is how can I reduce this number of new GDI objects created at resize. As a comparision, Microsoft Word 2013 also leaks GDI objects on resize, but only 2 or 3 not 20...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: "Most of the code" is plenty of explanation.  Forgetting to dispose System.Drawing objects in painting code is a standard oversight, you certainly get to exercise that when you resize the window.  Use a memory profiler if you can't find them back with a code review.

Comment: OK, but I don't do any custom painting on my own... I shall try with a memory profiler...

Comment: Are these 20-25 handles freed some time after resizing or are 20-25 handles are added on each resize?

Comment: On each resize, they are not freed, just stay there ultimately, after 2 minutes of intentional continous resizing crashing the application...